# How to get "Korean Hangul"?

Tags: 18.04, input-method

I have just upgraded to 18.04.1.  I need to type in Korean Hangul script, which on 16.04 was straightforward.  But the two language options in 18.04.1 in "Language and Region" from the settings menu are "Korean" and "Korean (101 and 104 Key compatible)".  Neither of them give Hangul script.  I see references on this site to a further option of "Korean Hangul" but cannot find how to load it or to select it.  Can anybody help please?

Comment: Have you installed the `ibus-hangul` package?

Comment: For some reason "Korean Hangul" just appeared as an option so I am now able to type in hangul.  Strange...  Thanks for your help.